# Process to call CLI exe not returning output

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, process, command-line-interface

I have a app that is doing some video processing.

I need to analyze the media before processing it.

The ffmpeg utility `ffprobe.exe` provides all the information I need.

However the code I am using will not return the text that appears when the command is ran in a `cmd` window :

```
public static string RunConsoleCommand(string command, string args)
{
    var consoleOut = "";

    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = command,
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };

        process.Start();
        consoleOut = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();

        return consoleOut;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Process class has some events to handle that :

```
public static string RunConsoleCommand(string command, string args)
{
    var consoleOut = "";

    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = command,
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };

        // Register for event and do whatever
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((snd, e) => { consoleOut += e.Data; });

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        return consoleOut;
    }
}
```

You also have ErrorDataReceived, which works the same way.

I'm using these events in some projects, and it works like a charm. Hope that helps.

**EDIT** : Fixed the code, you need to attach the handlers before you start the process.

Comment: Thanks @T.Fabre Your comment about ErrorDataReveived was the key.  ffmpeg applications output their log to this Error stream.

Comment: I've a conflict between `RedirectStandardOutput = true` and `process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((snd, e) => { consoleOut += e.Data; });`. I have to delete the first one and my programme returns me correctly the output, why ?

Comment: Not too sure. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) states that RedirectStandardOutput should be enabled for output to be sent to your event handler. You should probably open a new question with a code example, kindda hard to tell like that.